# Sort by reference document in Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, php-mongodb

I'm using DoctrineMongoDBOBundle with Symfony2.

I've a Document Product which has an annotation referenceOne to other Document Price.

I want to sort by price when I fetch with queryBuilder.

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:Product')
->field('geocoordinates')
->near('lat','lon')
->sort('hasPrice','desc')
```

But this doesn't works. Perhaps for the use of near?

It depends of toString() method of Document Price?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've a Document Product which has an annotation referenceOne to other Document Price.

There are no joins in MongoDB and I do not believe Doctrine does client side aggregation and sorting here. As such this wouldn't work anyway.

However sorting will work on a `$near` command ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/ ) which is what Doctrine should be using in this case, here you can see explicit support for `$near` being identified through the command you are using: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/commit/59f73cde2c15d171ff39afbf46c1a1339a51048c so your problem is the linked document, MongoDB has no JOINs.

Comment: Ok and what's the solution for this?

Comment: It depends upon your schema, normally to duplicate data between the two or you can do two range queries, on based upon the first collection of `prices` to get a list of `_id`s for the second collection, like in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `hasPrice` looks like it corresponds to a method, that perhaps checks whether the `price` reference is null or not. When referring to fields in ODM queries, names of class properties may be translated to the MongoDB field names (if they differ), but there is no support for method evaluation. Sammaye was correct that Doctrine does no client-side aggregation or sorting.

As an alternative, you may be able to sort on the `price.$id` field, which should group nonexistent values together in the results. Similarly, you could use the [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_exists) operator to match/exclude based on whether a document was actual referenced. References in ODM (excluding the "Simple" type) are stored as [MongoDBRef](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodbref.php) instances, which translate to objects with `$id`, `$ref`, and `$db` fields. As a result, you can query on those values just like any other field in your document.

Comment: Probably the name of the field is wrong, 'hasPrice' doesn't check if the Product has a Price but it return the Document Price so I don't sort by price.